# rails - Inheritanting class belongs to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm making an app where there will be two different kinds of products--default and user defined. I'm trying to associate only UserProducts with a user whereas a DefaultProduct will not require this field. I've looked online for a while but haven't found anything conclusive.

Here's the attempt I've tried so far:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, precence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }

  has_many :categories
end

class DefaultProduct < Product
  def self.model_name
    Product.model_name
  end
end

class UserProduct < Product
  def self.model_name
    Product.model_name
  end

  belongs_to :user # Causes the console to spew errors
end
```

I suspect using STI is a large contributor to the problem, but am newer to Rails and don't know of alternatives.

What's the general way to associate another model with an inheriting model in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All child models stay on parent table, so you must generate `user_id` field in `products` table and also add `type:string` field, for rails purposes.